# A basic django inclusion_tag not working

Tags: django, django-templates

I've written a small django custom template tag (inclustion_tag) which I want to use to display an html table showing the list vehicle brands and models in my VehicleBrand and VehicleModel models, however the template tag doesn't seem to be passing the variable from the database query in the template tag to the html.  I'm a newbie to django, so let me know if I'm missing something obvious.  Any help at all would be appreciated.

**Here is my template tag which is located in a templates directory under my application.  The template tag directory contains an _*init*_.py**

```
from django import template
from castester.models import VehicleBrand

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag("brand_model_select.html")
def brand_model_select():
    brand_list = VehicleBrand.objects.all()
    return {'brand_list':brand_list}
```

**Here is my model.py**

```
from django.db import models

class VehicleBrand(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    code = models.SlugField(primary_key=True)
```

**Here is my brand_model_select.html**

```
{% load castest_extras %}
<table>
    {% for brand in brand_list %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ brand.code }}</td>
            <td>{{ brand.description }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

**Here is the urls.conf line where I'm calling my html from a class based view.**

```
url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='brand_model_select.html'))
```

**Here is the output from a query on the model to prove the data is being retrieved from the database.**

```
>>> from castester.models import VehicleBrand
>>> VehicleBrand.objects.all().values()
[{'code': u'1', 'description': u'FORD'}, {'code': u'2', 'description': u'HOLDEN'}]
```

**A blank page is rendered with the following source.  Where is the query output I'm passing from the inclusion_tag?**

```
<table>

</table>
```

Comment: Please read the [`code layout`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout) section in the documentation that states: `Custom template tags and filters must live inside a Django app. If they relate to an existing app it makes sense to bundle them there; otherwise, you should create a new app to hold them. The app should contain a templatetags directory, at the same level as models.py, views.py, etc. If this doesn’t already exist, create it - don’t forget the __init__.py file to ensure the directory is treated as a Python package.`

Answer (score 1):

You're not meant to render `brand_model_select.html` directly. Instead, you should call your template tag from a different template:

```
# in url conf
`url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='homepage.html'))`

# in homepage.html
{% load castest_extras %}
{% brand_model_select %}
```

The point of an inclusion tag is that you can include it in another view. What you're doing right now doesn't use the template tag at all; instead, it just renders `brand_model_select.html` completely ignoring the tag.

Comment: Which kind of makes me wonder why OP thinks he needs an inclusion tag at all.

Comment: Thanks Dougal - it worked!!!  I'm only a beginner, so I'm only just getting coming to grips with some of the concepts.  Your answer really helped.